# Wireless camera for usb_cam

Tags: ros, wireless, camera, ar-pose, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for a wireless camera solution that could feed what it sees into the usb_cam node. I want to experiment with ar_pose however the camera is to be mounted on a quadcopter and obviously running a cam would be disadvantageous. Is there a camera system that would work over short range (5-10 m or so) that would permit this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33596/wireless-camera-for-usb_cam/) by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-05**:
@Chad Rockey experimented with a wireless camera at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try the Trek AI ball.  They are kinda expensive ($80) and run through batteries quickly, so I would power them externally.

http://www.thumbdrive.com/aiball/

There's a ROS MJPEG driver here:

https://github.com/chadrockey/mjpeg_network_camera

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1